# Paste options have disappeared

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013

I frequently copy selected cells from Excel and paste them into Outlook emails using the Ctrl C and V shortcuts.

Normally when I would use this method I could select/change the format of my data once I have pasted it(using the clipboard pop-up).

The pop-up still appears, but two of the choices have disappeared: "Use Destination Style" and "Paste as Picture". Of course, these are the only two that I use....HELP!

[image: These are my only choices now]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following steps to configure this:

1. Go to Outlook options
2. Go to the "Mail" tab
3. Under the "Compose Messages" section, hit the "Editor Options" button
4. In the new options box that appeared, go to the "Advanced" tab
5. Go to the "Cut, copy and paste" section.

There you have all the options. The one you are looking for is the "Show Paste Options button when content is pasted"

Just activate that option.

Comment: I've the same issue and that box is already selected. It's not that we don't have any paste options, just not all of them.

Comment: Seems like a "rights" issue then. Just tried it to see if there was an update that broke this, but it works fine for me. Did anything change in the environement? updates? GPO's? etc.?

Comment: This answer refers to the Outlook option _Show paste options button when content ist pasted_. However, even when the option is activated, the button still sometimes does not show. I experience this quite often (but not always) when trying to paste into an email reply (regardless of the format: HTML or not). To put it plain and simple, Microsoft has not implemented this feature _completely_.

Answer (score 1):

I had to untick "Show Paste Options button when content is pasted" and then select it again, then all the missing paste options appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem from today. Cannot paste onto email and Im not tech savvy so dont understand where all these things are on outlook?????

Go to Outlook options??
Go to the "Mail" tab???
Under the "Compose Messages" section, hit the "Editor Options" button??
In the new options box that appeared, go to the "Advanced" tab??
Go to the "Cut, copy and paste" section.??

It let me copy and paste all the above but still cannot paste in email

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1169254)